# Google Visualization - Data table is not visualized

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-visualization

I have implemented part of the functionality f my dashboard in different files and now I'm trying to merge them all together. My dashboard is getting an address from a geocoding field and retrieves url json data from a website. Then the data are visualized on the map,on a data table and on a scatter chart. Now I'm trying to merge the google map with the data table, but it's been a couple of hours that I'm getting the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'load'`
I'm trying to change the order that the libraries are loaded, but I didn't see any result. Here is part of my code. If you need more code, I'm glad to provide. It's just toolng and complex to provide it all at once.

Javascript:

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> <!-- jQuery CDN -->
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['table']});
google.setOnLoadCallBack(drawTable);
    var geocoder;
    var map;
    var latlng;
    var markers = [];
    var myPositionMarker = null;;
//Initializing the map
function initialize() {
var lat = 52.629729;
var lng = -1.131592;
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
getCrimeByLocation(lat, lng);
 }

 function fitBoundsMap(){
    //Zoom and center the map to fit the markers  
    //This logic could be conbined with the marker creation.  
    //Just keeping it separate for code clarity.  
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();  
    for (index in markers) {  
        var data = markers[index];
        bounds.extend(data.position);  
    }  
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
   function addMyPositionMarker(lat, lng) {
    if(myPositionMarker != null){
        myPositionMarker.setMap(null); // clearing prev req position
    }
            myPositionMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
        zIndex: 99999,
        icon: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/orZ4x.png'
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(myPositionMarker,'dragend',function(event) {
        getCrimeByLocation(event.latLng.lat(), event.latLng.lng());
    });
   }

   //Calling the JSON data from the website. 
 function getCrimeByLocation(lat, lng, date){
if(date == null){
    var d = new Date();
    date = d.getFullYear() + '-' + (d.getMonth()+1);
    //hardcoding as of now as jan 2014 data is not there, remove when req
    date = "2013-01";
}
$.getJSON( "http://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime?lat="+lat+"&lng="+lng+"&date="+date, function( data ) {
    while(markers.length > 0){
        markers.pop().setMap(null);
    }

    //marking the requested position
    addMyPositionMarker(lat, lng);

    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        //var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(val.location.latitude, val.location.longitude);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(val.location.latitude, val.location.longitude),
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            draggable: false,
            title: val.location.street.name
        });
        markers.push(marker); // saving markers for reference, so that we can remove them later;
    });

    if(markers.length > 0){
        fitBoundsMap();
    }
});
  }
   function geocodeCrimeLocation(date){
var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
if(date == null){
    var d = new Date();
    date = d.getFullYear() + '-' + (d.getMonth()+1);
    //hardcoding as of now as jan 2014 data is not there, remove when req
    date = "2013-01";
}
$.getJSON( "http://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime?lat="+latitude+"&lng="+longitude+"&date="+date, function(data) {
    while(markers.length > 0){
        markers.pop().setMap(null);
    }

    //marking the requested position
    addMyPositionMarker(latitude, longitude);

    $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        //var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(val.location.latitude, val.location.longitude);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(val.location.latitude, val.location.longitude),
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            draggable: false,
            title: val.location.street.name
        });
        markers.push(marker); // saving markers for reference, so that we can remove them later
    });

    if(markers.length > 0){
        fitBoundsMap();
    }       
});

} else {
  alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
}
});
}
function drawTable(){
var jsonData = $.ajax({
            url: "getJSONData.php",
            dataType:"json",
            async: false
        }).responseText;
        var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        dataTable.addColumn('string','category');
        dataTable.addColumn('string','context');
        dataTable.addColumn('number','id');
        dataTable.addColumn('string','location_subtype');
        dataTable.addColumn('string','location_type');
        dataTable.addColumn('string','month');
        dataTable.addColumn('string','persistent_id');
        dataTable.addColumn('string','street name');
        var json=JSON.parse(jsonData);
        for (var i=0; i<json.length; i++) {
            delete json[i].outcome_status;
            var row = [];       
            row.push(json[i].category);
            row.push(json[i].context);
            row.push(json[i].id);
            row.push(json[i].location_subtype);
            row.push(json[i].location_type);
            row.push(json[i].month);
            row.push(json[i].persistent_id);
            row.push(json[i].location.street.name);
            dataTable.addRow(row);
        }
        var chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
        chart.draw(dataTable, {width: 1000, height: 300});
}
```

HTML:

```
<body onload="initialize()">
<!-- <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 320px; height: 480px;"></div> -->
<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 480px;"></div>
<div>
    <input id="address" type="textbox" placeholder = "Enter address, or postcode">
    <input type="button" value="Encode" onclick="geocodeCrimeLocation()">
</div>
<br>
<div id = "pieChart_div">
</div>
<br>
<div id = "table_div">
</div>
</body>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('http://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime?lat=$_GET['latitude']&lng=$_GET['longitude']&date=2013-01'); 
$json = str_replace("\xe2\x80\xa8", '\\u2028', $json);
$json = str_replace("\xe2\x80\xa9", '\\u2029', $json);
echo $json;
?>
```

Thank you in advance fr your help.

Comment: javascript errors: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'load' v3_SO_fusionTablesGVizQueryTable.html:18`,
`Uncaught ReferenceError: getCrimeByLocation is not defined v3_SO_fusionTablesGVizQueryTable.html:36`, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined v3_SO_fusionTablesGVizQueryTable.html:52`

Comment: The attached code, is part of my code. I can edit my question in order to attach all my code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I have just edited my question and thanks for replying. Basically, I have observed that the problem arises when I include both Maps and Visualization APIs. I need them however in the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the trouble is `google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['table']});`

I believe this due to you not including the visualization API script, like you have for maps. Try adding the following with your other script includes:

`<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>`

The Visualization API docs:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/index

Comment: I did the change and now I get the same error for `google.setOnLoadCallBack(drawTable);`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Maps API, I've only used visualization, so I am just suggesting things now. You can actually draw maps with markers using the visualization API, so then you can use similar functions for the table and the map using a single API: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/map. I'd try removing the maps API include and commenting the map code and see if you can draw a table, at least then you know what is (or what isn't) causing it. You're also including 2 jQuery versions which might not be helping.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions mate! I'll try and see where it goes. Cheers

Comment: the method is called setOnLoadCallback (lowercase b)

Comment: It was my typo. I tried now to display the data table and the scatter graph and they are displayed OK. But when I include the google maps API, then I get this error. If anyone else could provide any hint, I would be grateful. Thanks

Comment: You are still not including [the AJAX API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start) (or is that another "typo"?)

Comment: That is what causes the error you are reporting `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'load'` on the line `google.load(...)`

Comment: @geocodezip Thanks again. One last question. When I was implementing the data table and scatter chart, I used php to retrieve the data as yu can see on the question. The map retrieves the data via `getJSON()`. I was thinking of wrapping this either just on php or just with `getJSON()`. Which one do you think that is the best to keep? Cheers.

Comment: Since you aren't doing anything that is *required* to be done server-side, the only reason I can think of for using the server-side code is if the site you are grabbing data from blocks cross-domain requests.